# Order increment id not saving correctly

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, sql, increment-id

I have code that saves order details to a custom table:

```
    foreach($links as $link) {
        $pdf = Mage::getModel('custom_sales/pdf');
        $pdf->setOrderId($order->getId())
            ->setOrderIncrementId($order->getIncrementId())
            ->setLink($link)
            ->save();
    }
```

The code saves the records, and the order_id and link columns are correct, but the order increment id's are completely wrong e.g. an order with increment ID `15070100396216` has it's increment ID saved as `4294967295`

The table structure is as follows:

```
  `entity_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `order_id` INTEGER(14) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `order_increment_id` INTEGER(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `link` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

Does anyone have any clue why this might be happening?

Comment: Datatype increment_id in sales_flat_order table is varchar(50)  try to change datatype of increment_id to varchar(50) in your table that may resolve your issue.

Comment: hi @aman_uni, could you please create an answer? I want to accept it, since this sorted out my issue!

Comment: Thanks i have created answer. It would be great if you vote up also. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen your table structure you should use below mentioned solution that resolve your issue.

Datatype `increment_id` in `sales_flat_order` table is `varchar(50)` try to change datatype of `order_increment_id` to `varchar(50)` in your table that may resolve your issue.